# How to combine radio buttons with comboboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I recently just got introduced to windows form and coding in general. There are a lot of things I am stuck on. Im trying to learn by myself and searching online but it is much much harder than expected.

I am trying to create a menu and in the menu you can select sandwiches with radio buttons, but I wanted to make options of choosing regular or large sandwiches. In the combo box there are two options, a regular for $3.00 and a large for $4.00. But there are different pricing for different sandwiches so they are not all $3.00 for regular and $4.00 for a large
How do I code it so it will run like this

1. You select the sandwich you want with a radio button
2. You then choose a regular or a large from the combo box, based on two options you choose from the combo box, it will add however much the sandwich you selected to the total.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, this is a very broad question. Have you attempted to approach the problem and do you have any code you can show us? If so, please post it and narrow down your problem to a more specific question. Also for future reference, please [see this section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for general guidelines on asking questions.

Comment: There are mnay ways to go about it.  One is to develop a Class to hold the Name of the Sandwich along with the Price for a Small/Large.  Store a reference to the Sandwich instance in the Tag() Property of the RadioButton.  When that sandwich RadioButton is selected, cast the Tag() property to the Class type and update the values in the ComboBox with the associated values.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Sorry, I'll try to narrow it down. I have attempted to try to do this, but I'm just so confused on how coding works. Trying my best to understand, all I've done is basic stuff such as creating a tax calculator. The code I have currently is just the implementing tax into the total. I think it'll  be easier if I show you.
http://gyazo.com/f9b33964b153d51247b1a014d380b31b
So when you select the sandwich and choose which ever size in the combo box which states the price. The amount in the combo box that shows which is 6.00 is then added total box which will be update when changed